# comparing two columns data with same categories in a plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset where the `MaterialState_manual` and `MaterialState_pipeline` feature has the same categories as shown in the table. such as `T61`, `190c_250` and more. The number of precipitates in column `Precipitate_manual` is different than the column `Prepitates_pipeline`.

[image]

Now I want to create a hist plot to compare the same category two lines to show `Precipitates_manual` vs `Precipitate_pipeline` with all the categories we have in `MaterialStates`.

What I did here, but does not shows the categories.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas


df['Precipitates_manual'].hist()
df['Precipitates_pipeline'].hist()
```

The output:

[image]

What I did in excel but in python still struggling.
[image]

Comment: What deos x axies elemnts `190c_250h` or `190c_2500h` where deos they coming from?

Comment: These are the categories of the data. for example, I want to check `T61` object in manual vs pipeline. so a histogram should shows more objects in manual than the pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-shape your dataframe by combining [**`pandas melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and [**`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df = pd.melt(frame = df,
             id_vars = 'MaterialState_manual',
             var_name = 'Precipitates_type',
             value_name = 'Precipitates_value').groupby(by = ['MaterialState_manual', 'Precipitates_type']).sum().reset_index()
```

In order to get a dataframe like this one:

```
   MaterialState_manual      Precipitates_type  Precipitates_value
0            190c_1000h    Precipitates_manual                  54
1            190c_1000h  Precipitates_pipeline                  61
2           190c_25000h    Precipitates_manual                  90
3           190c_25000h  Precipitates_pipeline                  68
4            190c_2500h    Precipitates_manual                 111
5            190c_2500h  Precipitates_pipeline                 137
6             190c_250h    Precipitates_manual                 100
7             190c_250h  Precipitates_pipeline                  93
8            190c_5000h    Precipitates_manual                  77
9            190c_5000h  Precipitates_pipeline                  78
10                  T61    Precipitates_manual                  60
11                  T61  Precipitates_pipeline                  48
```

In this way you can simply use [**`seaborn.barplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
sns.barplot(data = df, 
            ax = ax, 
            x = 'MaterialState_manual', 
            y = 'Precipitates_value', 
            hue = 'Precipitates_type')
```

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


categories_list = ['T61', '190c_250h', '190c_1000h', '190c_2500h', '190c_5000h', '190c_25000h']
df_length = 100


np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['MaterialState_manual'] = np.random.choice(a = categories_list, size = df_length, replace = True)
df['Precipitates_manual'] = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 10, size = df_length)
df['Precipitates_pipeline'] = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 10, size = df_length)


df = pd.melt(frame = df,
             id_vars = 'MaterialState_manual',
             var_name = 'Precipitates_type',
             value_name = 'Precipitates_value').groupby(by = ['MaterialState_manual', 'Precipitates_type']).sum().reset_index()


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.barplot(data = df,
            ax = ax,
            x = 'MaterialState_manual',
            y = 'Precipitates_value',
            hue = 'Precipitates_type')

plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: You can check the question again, I a little bit changed the structure of the data but what you suggest is not possible because I have more than 5000 records, and adding `precipitate_type` for each record is somehow time-consuming. Please have a look now to the table.

Comment: You are not supposed to add `precipitate_type` manually to your code: [**`pandas.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) will take care of it by itself; you will end up with a smaller dataframe with only 10-12 rows, where each row represents the sum of `Precipitates` value, split up by its type